# Negative lookahead in LR parsing algorithm

Tags: parsing, generator, conflict, resolve, regex-lookarounds

Consider such a rule in grammar for an LR-family parsing generator (e.g YACC, BISON, etc.):

```
Nonterminal : [ lookahead not in {Terminal1, ..., TerminalN} ] Rule ;
```

It's an ordinary rule, except that it has a restriction: a phrase produced with this rule cannot begin with `Terminal1, ..., TerminalN`. (Surely, this rule can be replaced with a set of usual rules, but it will result in a bigger grammar). This can be useful for resolving conflicts.

The question is, is there a modification of LR table construction algorithm that accepts such restrictions? It seems to me that such a modification is possible (like precedence relations).

Surely, it can be checked in runtime, but I mean compile-time check (a check which is performed while building parsing table, like `%prec`, `%left`, `%right` and `%nonassoc` directives in yacc-compartible generators.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this shouldn't be possible, but I also don't see any obvious reason why it would be useful. Do you have an example in mind?

The easiest way to do this would be to do the grammar transform you mention in parentheses. This would make a larger grammar, but it won't artificially increase the number of LR states.

The basic transformation, with only a bit of hand-waving:

For any production with terminal restrictions:

- If the production starts with a non-nullable non-terminal, replace the non-terminal with a terminal-restricted version.
- If the production starts with a terminal in the terminal restriction list, remove the production
- If the production starts with a terminal not in the terminal restriction list, no change is necessary.

If a production starts with a nullable non-terminal, you have to create two versions of the nullable non-terminal, one of which is always null, and the other of which is non-nullable; and then create two versions of the production, one starting with each of the new non-terminals. Then apply the above transforms, but interpreting "starts with" to mean "starts with after any always-null non-terminals."

You don't actually need to modify the grammar, since the above transformations can be done on the fly during the construction of the underlying SLR machine, at least for LR(0) and LALR(1) constructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I have an example in mind, it's ECMA-262 grammar (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1, e.g. section 12.4). Since this grammar uses `Expression` production both with and without restrictions, we have to double that grammar part which describes `Experssion`. In my LALR(1) parser generator, it leads to much more states (350 vs 470). It would be very nice to keep 350 states and satisfy restrictions.